# Is it possible to name play evolution sql scripts?

Tags: sql, playframework-2.4

evolution sql scripts should be named

- 1.sql,
- 2.sql,
- XXX.sql

according to documentation.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Evolutions#Running-evolutions-using-compile-time-DI

Is there any possibility to change naming convention to

- 1_create__customers.sql
- 2_create__orders.sql
- 3_alter__customers__add__home_address.sql

like it RoR: 
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration

Yes, I evaluated https://github.com/flyway/flyway-play
and we can switch to it.

Right now I'm looking for default play functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

Create a new file at this path: `your/modules/folder/EvolutionsModule.scala`

Then, add the following:

```scala
package your.modules.folder

import javax.inject._

import play.api.db.evolutions._
import play.api.inject.{ Module }
import play.api.libs.Collections
import play.api.{ Configuration, Environment }
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

class EvolutionsModule extends Module {
  def bindings(environment: Environment, configuration: Configuration) = {
    Seq(
      bind[EvolutionsConfig].toProvider[DefaultEvolutionsConfigParser],
      bind[EvolutionsReader].to[YourEvolutionsReader],
      bind[EvolutionsApi].to[DefaultEvolutionsApi],
      bind[ApplicationEvolutions].toProvider[ApplicationEvolutionsProvider].eagerly
    )
  }
}

@Singleton
class YourEvolutionsReader @Inject()(environment: Environment) extends EvolutionsReader {

  def evolutions(db: String): Seq[Evolution] = {

    val upsMarker = """^#.*!Ups.*$""".r
    val downsMarker = """^#.*!Downs.*$""".r

    val UPS = "UPS"
    val DOWNS = "DOWNS"
    val UNKNOWN = "UNKNOWN"

    val mapUpsAndDowns: PartialFunction[String, String] = {
      case upsMarker() => UPS
      case downsMarker() => DOWNS
      case _ => UNKNOWN
    }

    val isMarker: PartialFunction[String, Boolean] = {
      case upsMarker() => true
      case downsMarker() => true
      case _ => false
    }

    val folder = environment.getFile(Evolutions.directoryName(db))
    val sqlFiles = folder.listFiles()
      .filter(file => file.getName.indexOf(".sql") > -1)
      .sortBy(file => {
        val fileName = file.getName
        val nameAfterSqlNumber = fileName.split("\\.")(0).split("_").drop(1).mkString("") + ".sql"
        val sqlNumber = fileName.split("\\.")(0).split("_")(0).toInt
        val newPrefix = "%07d".format(sqlNumber)
        newPrefix + nameAfterSqlNumber
      })
      .toSeq
    sqlFiles.zip(1 to sqlFiles.size)
      .map {
        case (file, revision) => {
          val script = FileUtils.readFileToString(file)
          val parsed = Collections.unfoldLeft(("", script.split('\n').toList.map(_.trim))) {
            case (_, Nil) => None
            case (context, lines) => {
              val (some, next) = lines.span(l => !isMarker(l))
              Some((next.headOption.map(c => (mapUpsAndDowns(c), next.tail)).getOrElse("" -> Nil),
                context -> some.mkString("\n")))
            }
          }.reverse.drop(1).groupBy(i => i._1).mapValues { _.map(_._2).mkString("\n").trim }
          Evolution(
            revision,
            parsed.getOrElse(UPS, ""),
            parsed.getOrElse(DOWNS, "")
          )
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Go to your `applications.conf`, then add these lines. This is for replacing the default `EvolutionsModule` with our very own.

```
play.modules {
    enabled += "your.modules.folder.EvolutionsModule"
    disabled += "play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsModule"
}
```

Explanation for the first block of text:

- According to the source code, evolutions are added solely based on a single class and method - the `EvolutionsReader` and the method `evolutions`.
- After running the `evolutions` method, the evolutions module will rely on the database entries generated. So, we only need to override this method with our own.
- Despite the huge block of code, it's actually a minor edit of the source code. I replaced the functionality of the `loadResource` function with the list of files inside the evolutions sql files folder. The rest of it is a straight-up copy of the `evolutions` method in `EvolutionsApi.scala`

The source codes quoted [by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43135225) are most likely utility functions - the Evolutions module doesn't actually rely on it. I couldn't find any significant usage of `fileName` and `resourceName` for running the `evolutions`. Instead, they're all referencing the `play_evolutions` table.

Reference: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/6919

Comment: @Sergey That's all right. IMO, dropping evolutions completely and switching is the correct decision (and drop slick too, but that's another story). but I couldn't because I'm inheriting a project. Still, I wanted this question to have the correct answer for future reference for me and fellow code maintainers, and especially because I'll be using Scala for a long, long time.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible, the source code:

```
def fileName(db: String, revision: Int): String = s"${directoryName(db)}/${revision}.sql"
```

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.x/framework/src/play-jdbc-evolutions/src/main/scala/play/api/db/evolutions/Evolutions.scala#L103

```
def resourceName(db: String, revision: Int): String = s"evolutions/${db}/${revision}.sql"
```

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.x/framework/src/play-jdbc-evolutions/src/main/scala/play/api/db/evolutions/Evolutions.scala#L108

```
@Singleton
class EnvironmentEvolutionsReader @Inject() (environment: Environment) extends ResourceEvolutionsReader {

  def loadResource(db: String, revision: Int) = {
    environment.getExistingFile(Evolutions.fileName(db, revision)).map(new FileInputStream(_)).orElse {
      environment.resourceAsStream(Evolutions.resourceName(db, revision))
    }
  }
}
```

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.5.x/framework/src/play-jdbc-evolutions/src/main/scala/play/api/db/evolutions/EvolutionsApi.scala#L471-L479

So, as it describet in the documentation, you can only use the number `{revision}.sql`